# Enumeration vs Interface for constants

Tags: vb.net, oop

Is it a good design practice to change an enumeration type:

```
Public Enum EnumerationType
    EnumerationMember1
    EnumerationMember2
End Enum
```

To an interface base with implementor classes (even if they are empty)?

```
Public Interface IEnumerationType
End Interface
Public Class EnumerationMember1 : Implements IEnumerationType
End Class
Public Class EnumerationMember2 : Implements IEnumerationType
End Class
```

For extensibility purposes.

Is there any downside? Is there any case in which is preferable to use just an enum?

Comment: For extensibility purposes you can create your own class. What kind of extensibility you want to add?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just extend the enum? I don't see why you would need the empty classes...

Comment: What do you mean and Interface for a constants?

Comment: @sloth You cannot extend the enum with a method if you need.

Comment: @Blam Using the class type as if it was an enumeration member.

Comment: You'll have to give out more context. What is the enumeration used for? If the enum is just a list of color index, it'll be different if it represent a class type.

Comment: @user4388177 Why do you need a method on an enum?

Comment: EnumerationMember1.CompatibleWith(EnumerationMember2)

Answer (score 0):

INTERFACES used for contracts between classes 
that is when you have two non-related classes sharing some methods

Enumeration  type stores special values. These are named constants. With an Enum, we replace magic constants throughout a program.
This improves code clarity,
organizes code
and makes code easier to maintain

For extensibility purposes it is better to use interface cause you will have methods properties and you can inherit the class later

```
Public Enum
```

with interface you have enumeration with advanced options so what the downsides will be  ? No downside :)

Comment: I don't think it will have a big impact on performances, but I was wondering why I could not find any example online. Seems to me a pretty simple and useful future-proofing in some cases; if there is nothing else that cannot be done with this approach that can be done with the enum instead.

Comment: Well we always find our ways and methods while coding , it isn't necessary  to find someone did it the way you did

Comment: The answer is neither correct nor incorrect, it just says there are no downsides. I will wait for more input before assuming it is true.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entire clear what you're after, but take a look at the strongly typed enum pattern.

```
''' <completionlist cref="EnumerationType"/>
Class EnumerationType

    Private Key As String

    Public Shared ReadOnly Member1 As EnumerationMember1 = New EnumerationMember1("EnumerationMember1")
    Public Shared ReadOnly Member2 As EnumerationMember2 = New EnumerationMember2("EnumerationMember2")

    Private Sub New(key as String)
        Me.Key = key
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Me.Key
    End Function
End Class
```

So when you use it, it *looks* like an enum:

```
Sub Main

    DoSomething(EnumerationType.EnumerationMember1)
    DoSomething(EnumerationType.EnumerationMember2)

End Sub

Sub DoSomething(test As IEnumerationType)
    Console.WriteLine(test.ToString())
End Sub
```

but you can easily add functionality to it (like explicit conversions, or a way to iterate over all members using a shared dictionary, or whatever comes to your mind).

It's typesafe, and using the magic `completionlist` comment will enable Intellisense support.

Comment: It is an interesting implementation; but, since the EnumerationMember are of the same type, the only way to differenciate their behavior will be to use the hardcoded string as conditional.

Comment: To be honest I'm not exactly sure what you're after.

Comment: I'm not looking for a solution to a specific problem, I just wanted to investigate the possible downside of replacing an enumeration with an interface an its members with classes. As far as I see, you can do exactly the same you can do with an Enum plus you add extensibility (the members can potentially contain logic). Although, I might be missing something really obvious (hereby I asked the question on Stackoverflow).

Comment: You can still use the approach used in my answer. The members don't have to be of the same type (see my edit).

Comment: It becomes the same as my initial idea; To be able to assign both members to the same variable, you will have to implement the same interface.

Comment: @user4388177 either that, or use a base class.